# ping ignoring -w (timeout) switch

Tags: windows-10, ping, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to simulate an intermittent ping timeout by adding the -w switch but it seems to be ignoring that switch.

The host* I'm pinging typically replies around 108 ms   so if I set /w to anything lower than that I would have thought I'd see timeouts,  but no matter what I set it to,  I get no timeouts.

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping www.google.com -w 5

Pinging www.google.com [216.58.198.228] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.198.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54
Reply from 216.58.198.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54
Reply from 216.58.198.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54
Reply from 216.58.198.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 216.58.198.228:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 10ms
```

Am I doing something wrong,  or misunderstanding the situation?  Or does this switch simply not work?

**Replaced with www.google.com in the example, to avoid including the actual ip address and hostname that I'm using*

Comment: I can confirm this bug. What is interesting, the timeout setting is obeyed if you ping a non-answering host (try 8.8.8.7).

Comment: Still got the bug this day but maybe my Windows10 version is not up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [following documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> When specifying very small numbers for timeout, the Ping reply can be
>   received even if timeout milliseconds have elapsed.

After some testing, this seems to explain your issue. I have tested pinging example.com, wich replies between 70-85ms for me. When setting timeout to 80ms, some pings fail, and some don't. So, somewhere below 80ms starts to be "very small".

Comment: Pinging a host with a consistent 200ms+ latency and setting timeout to 100ms does nothing, the flag is ignored and nothing is timed out. This appears to be a bug in Windows 10 as it doesn't follow specifications.

Answer (score 0):

If I set very high timeouts eg 300000ms (=5 minutes), this seems to work as expected. However, if I set low timeouts eg 1-100ms, they seem to be ignored.